# Mongoid - remove entity from M:N collection but not delete it

Tags: ruby, many-to-many, mongoid

I need to remove related entity from collection.
So for example I have M:N relation: project which has multiple users (and users can have multiple projects).

How can I remove user from project, but do not delete him?

```
# this removes user from project, but also deletes user
project.users.find(id: user._id).remove
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have band and it has multiple tags:

```
band = Band.all[1]
=> #<Band _id: 599d2c8a9d1fa2c5498024cc, name: "test_band", tag_ids: [BSON::ObjectId('599d2c8a9d1fa2c5498024cd'), BSON::ObjectId('599d2c8a9d1fa2c5498024ce'), BSON::ObjectId('599d2c8a9d1fa2c5498024cf')]>
```

Then if we try to delete one of related tag objects:

```
band.tags.delete(Tag.find(id: '599d2c8a9d1fa2c5498024cd')
...
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | test_development.update | SUCCEEDED | 0.000634s
=> #<Tag _id: 599d2c8a9d1fa2c5498024cd, name: "test_tag1", band_ids: []>
```

It will be removed from `band.tags` array:

```
irb(main):088:0> band
=> #<Band _id: 599d2c8a9d1fa2c5498024cc, name: "test", tag_ids: [BSON::ObjectId('599d2c8a9d1fa2c5498024ce'), BSON::ObjectId('599d2c8a9d1fa2c5498024cf')]>
```

But that Tag still present as object:

```
Tag.find(id: '599d2c8a9d1fa2c5498024cd')
=> #<Tag _id: 599d2c8a9d1fa2c5498024cd, name: "test_tag1", band_ids: []>
```

Comment: but I don't have `project_id` attribute. I have an array `project_ids`, which I cannot set to `nil` as I want to remove just one item, not the whole collection.

Comment: What if just remove an element from that array like this: `project.users.delete(user._id)` ?

Comment: No, delete will delete document!

Comment: @yesterday I updated answer with example, please take a look